# Save object from Parse as image instead of PFFileObject in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, pffile

I am trying to save images from Parse to a list. Now I am saving the images as PFFileObject, but I want to save them as uiimages instead.
I am using this code:

```
var weblinks = [String]()
    var webnames = [String]()
    var webobjects= [PFFileObject]()
    var webimages = [UIImage]()

func fetchFromParse() {
        let query = PFQuery(className:"FirstClass")
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                for object in objects! {
                    self.webnames.append(object["webnames"]! as! String)
                    self.weblinks.append(object["weblinks"]! as! String)
                    self.webimages.append(object["webobjects"]! as! PFFileObject
                }
                self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
            } else {
                print(error!)
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I do to save the images to webimages instead of webobjects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save images as `UIImage` directly because Parse doesn't know what that is.

`PFFileObject` exists to help you upload any kind of file, like images, as long as its converted to `Data`.

Getting a `Data` object from an `UIImage` is as simple as

```
let data = image.pngData()
```

and you can initialize an image with a `Data` object like this

```
let image = UIImage(data: data)
```

Both methods return optionals, so you'll have to deal with that, but you can use that `Data` value on `PFFileObject` to upload your images to Parse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.